# Getting value of ajax json variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, web

I have this in my javascript function

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "pie_chart_community.php",
    community_id: $c_id,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

I want to get the community_id in another PHP page. How can I get it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the community_id variable in session data?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $_SESSION['community_id'] = SOME_ID; ?>
```

Then to Access it:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['community_id'];?>
```